# OSX gettimeofday syscall on x86_64 seems to not work

Tags: macos, x86-64, system-calls, gettimeofday

I'm making a call to gettimeofday via the syscall instruction using 64bit code.

I can't get any results back and am getting told via Dtrace that the call worked with no errors, but the registers I get back from the call are garbage.

I do the following:

```
lea rdi, [rel timeval]   ;buffer for 16bytes
mov rsi, 0               ;no need of timezone
mov rax, 0x2000074       ;gettimeofday
syscall
```

On return rax is neither 0 nor -1, and the buffer never gets any data.

Please can somebody check this and see if they can get a working call. I've no idea what is going on.

Best Regards

Chris

ps this is the example code I just tried, it dosn't return anything but 0.

```
    SECTION .text

    global _main
_main:
    lea rdi, [rel buffer]
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000074
    syscall

    mov rdi, [rel buffer]
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall

    SECTION .data
buffer:
    times 16 db 0
```

Comment: Can you post the commands you use to compile this just in case.

Comment: Sorry folks that should have read: rdi, rsi and rax ! I just types it in here wrong, the code does use rdi, rsi and rax !

Comment: It's part of a peace of code I'm compiling with NASM, I use this to compile: nasm -f macho64 main.nasm, then link with: ld -macosx_version_min 10.6 -o main -e _main main.o

Comment: Full code is available here if anybody wishes to see it: https://github.com/vygr/Asm-Kernel, my last checkin entry disabled the non working call, feel free to uncomment and try for yourself.

Comment: The code in question is in file sys/task_sleep, the first section of that code is trying to make the gettimeofday call. It fails to return anything. I am useing NASM 'altreg' setting so registers rdi == r7, rsi ==r6, rax == r0. The syscall macros can be found in syscall.inc.

Comment: I've added a test.nasm file to the repo, just a short example of this going wrong, about 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the APIs, you need to point:

1) RDI to the timeval structure:

```
_STRUCT_TIMEVAL
{
    __darwin_time_t         tv_sec;         /* seconds */
    __darwin_suseconds_t    tv_usec;        /* and microseconds */
};
```

DarwinTime is a QWORD and DarwinSuSeconds is a DWORD.

2) RSI to the timezone structure.
Just point that to a 2xQWORD scratch buffer if you don't like its output.

3) RDX to the `mach_absolute_time` structure
This is a 1xQWORD buffer

Setting either of the above RSI, RDX, RDI to 0x0 rather than pointers might be getting rejected as it can trigger an internal exception.  (Check if the return value is `-EFAULT`.)

---

Also note that POSIX deprecates `gettimeofday` in favour of `clock_gettime` (which has a seconds / nanosecond time struct), so you might want to use that instead.